# PHP-FPM + Nginx docker-compose stack without duplicate volumes

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, laradock

I have the following docker-compose in my Vagrant + Ansible local development stack (master for Ansible execution, node-1 for VPS simulation):

```yml
version: "3.8"

networks:
  frontend:
    driver: bridge
  backend:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  nginx:
    driver: local

services:

### PHP ########################################################################
  php:
    image: php:7.4.8-fpm-buster
    expose:
      - "9000"
    networks:
      - backend
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/docker/php/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini:ro
      - /usr/src/app/docker/php/zzz.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/zzz.ini:ro
      - /usr/src/app/docker/php/zzz.conf:/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zzz.conf:ro
      - nginx:/usr/share/nginx

### Nginx ######################################################################
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.1
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    depends_on:
      - php
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    environment:
      - NGINX_HOST=app.test
      - NGINX_PORT=80
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/docker/nginx/templates:/etc/nginx/templates
      - /usr/src/app/docker/src/phpinfo.php:/usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php
      - nginx:/usr/share/nginx
```

I want to test PHP-FPM with a simple phpinfo.php file, which is mounted from the host to the following location in the Nginx container: `/usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php`

Running this file I'm getting the infamous blank page response in my browser. Maybe I have bad Nginx settings, so I executing `cgi-fcgi` directly on both PHP and Nginx container also, but `/status` and `/ping` works just fine:

```sh
$ ansible node-1 -b -a "docker exec -it app_php_1 /bin/bash -c 'SCRIPT_NAME=/ping SCRIPT_FILENAME=/ping QUERY_STRING=full REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect 127.0.0.1:9000'"
node-1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.8
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0

pong
$ ansible node-1 -b -a "docker exec -it app_nginx_1 /bin/bash -c 'SCRIPT_NAME=/ping SCRIPT_FILENAME=/ping QUERY_STRING=full REQUEST_METHOD=GET cgi-fcgi -bind -connect php:9000'"
node-1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.8
Content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate, max-age=0

pong
```

In the next step, I copy with `curl` a simple `phpinfo` file into `/usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php` location in `php` container and surprise, it's returning the expected HTML output. So the issue is probably related to file permissions between the containers, volumes and host mounted files.

But this approach creates a new problem on it's own, because now I have two different versions of a file between the `php` and `nginx` container. One is host mounted, the another one is rewritten by the `curl` command, both under the path of the same volume:

```sh
vagrant@master:~$ ansible node-1 -b -a "docker exec -it app_php_1 cat /usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php"
node-1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
<?php

phpinfo();
vagrant@master:~$ ansible node-1 -b -a "docker exec -it app_nginx_1 'cat /usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php"
node-1 | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

I need some advice in the following questions:

- Is there a way to create FastCGI connection between a PHP and Nginx (or Apache) container without exposing a volume to both containers?
- If it's only possible if I install both PHP and Nginx in the same container, in my mind this is defeats the "one process for one thing" paradigm. I don't consider this a solution.
- Maybe a less painful approach would be using a **multi-stage build** Dockerfile? But again, PHP have it's needed system packages on it's own, so this is probably not gonna work...
- Lot of resources on the internet considering getting your app into containers with `git` as a bad practice, but seems like mounting from the host can create another problem, because if a file modified inside a container, the same mounted volume can have a different file version in another container.
- A `COPY` command in a `Dockerfile` can be a viable solution to not have host mounted problems like in my case (duplicate file versions, if one container modifying the file)?

**Please give me some advice how to properly handle persisting data with Docker Volumes between multiple containers, if you consider using CI/CD on the future also. Thank You!**

**Update 2020-07-30:**

If I bind mounting the same file both into php and nginx containers (so I abandone the named volumes), suddanly it works:

```yml
- /usr/src/app/docker/src/phpinfo.php:/usr/share/nginx/html/phpinfo.php
```

However this one doesn't:

```yml
- nginx:/usr/share/nginx
```

**Why is this different behavior with named volumes and why it works with bind mounts?**

I examined the [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) project and it also uses bind mounts almost everywhere. Seems like I should only use volumes when my code created inside the containers (like a database), am I right? What's happening with volumes if I want to expose the same location to multiple containers?

Answer (score 0):

Build process:

1. Build a single image using the base containing php-fpm and apache (php-fpm-apache)
2. Create a pod with two containers with the same image but different commands running in the foreground.
3. (2.1) 1st container with Apache (with root user)[root].
4. (2.2) 2nd container with php-fpm (with continua user in the example)[non-root]

Ref example: [here](https://github.com/srijanone/vega/blob/develop/starterkits/drupal8-php-fpm-apache/docker-compose.yml)

Comment: Link to example is not working anymore (leading to an HTTP 404 error).